# Name of G-d changing

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names

Is there a Source for the statement that when Mashiach comes the Name of G-d will no longer be יהוה but יהיה ?

Comment: Please indicate where you have seen this statement.

Comment: What you wrote spells "He will be" -- appropriate for the Messianic Age.  Remember, the Adon Olam reads:  וְהוּא הָיָה וְהוּא הֹוֶה וְהוּא יִהְיֶה בְּתִפְאָרָה.

Comment: Heard it in a shiur by Rabbi Tatz Many years ago...